# Core JavaScript is not included in all pages

Tags: javascript, 8

I'm developing a theme in Drupal 8. This is my theme.libraries.yml file:

```
default:
 version: 1.x
 css:
  theme:
   css/bootstrap.css: {}
   css/style.css: {}
   css/font-awesome.min.css: {}
   css/animate.min.css: {}
 js:
    js/galip.js: {}
```

When I try to view the source of the front page page, I see the JavaScript files like ready.min.js. jquery.min.js, jquery.once.min.js which I don't see in the login page and other pages.

Why is this happening? How do I include the core JavaScript files in all pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal 8 adds little to no javascript by default, and thankfully doesn't force jQuery on us any more :)

You need to declare your dependencies explicitly:

```
default:
 version: 1.x
 css:
  theme:
   css/bootstrap.css: {}
   css/style.css: {}
   css/font-awesome.min.css: {}
   css/animate.min.css: {}
 js:
    js/galip.js: {}
 dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - etc...
```